# How to remove extra parenthesis in subfigure label

Tags: labels, subcaption, subfig

I am using the following code for subfigures (suggested by [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3):_Figures,_Subfigures_and_Tables#Subfigures)):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\normalsize Figure \thefigure. (\alph{subfigure}):}
```

which is producing the output:

[image]

How to remove those extra braces around the entire label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because the default setup of `subfigure` environment is defined as follows :

> The default settings for subcaptions are: `margin=0pt,size=smaller,labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,
>   skip=6pt,list=false,hypcap=false`

See [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) documentation.

So you can patch this by adding `[labelformat=simple]` in the option of `subcaption`. This code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}    %%Adding option to remove parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\normalsize Figure \thefigure. (\alph{subfigure}):}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Test}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Test}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Total}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output which seems to be what you expected :

[image: output]